# Change material design UI color in IDEA and other JetBrains IDE

Tags: material-design, phpstorm, webstorm

I am new to material design UI plugin that's offered in IDEA.

Basically, it is the most satisfying editor theme I've ever used, however, the comment of this UI is a little bit not obvious than what I expected.

When I used Darcula theme, the comment is brighter and easier to recognize.

Is there a way to change the comment color of the material UI theme?

[image]

Comment: So .. what's exactly is the problem? Those colors should be editable (as it's just a color scheme) in a standard place -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme`. Color for comments may be defined at per-language level .. or at "Language Defaults".

Comment: What I mean is that, if I change the color scheme, I will change almost all the color of the editor, but if I just want to change the color of the comment ("# test" in my example) to make it more outstanding without changing anything else? Is there a way to modify it?

Comment: ??? I still do not understand the problem. You **edit** the color scheme -- you edit individual styles in existing color scheme. If it does not allow you to edit that scheme directly -- make a copy (save as) and then edit it.